# Is there a way to display custom message for addin actions on top of the calendar appointment?

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js

When I click on my outlook addin, it will display a grey message on top of the calendar appointment saying "MyAdd is working on your XXX request" (like the "outlook test plugin is working on your Insert Default Gist request" message in the screenshot below). I believe this is done by Office.js underneath.

Now, I want to display certain error messages of my addin that way too. But I do not see any outlook [APIs on the Office DevCenter](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.1/index) likely provides such functionality. Want to know if this is doable? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using [NotificationMessages](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.3/NotificationMessages) object. This object minimum mailbox requirement version set to 1.3 level API. Link to the documentation you have provided is leading to 1.1 level API.

Comment: One more question. We also want to insert a link in the message body the users can click. But looks like NotificationMessages only takes string as message, not html. So I think that is not feasible given the existing API. Just want to confirm there isn't anything that I missed. Thanks!

Comment: @CodingFanSteve NotificationMessages JSONmessage.message property is accepting the text string of maximum 150 characters, per documentation. You will not be able to set HTML as the input for the message. You didn't miss anything. If you would like to get this feature in upcoming releases, you may post your use case at [uservoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/)